# Get ID-specific div from a remote page, then edit its content

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Say we have a div with id MydDiv in the remote page `site.com/page1.html`

We want to get this div only from the page in a way that allow us to manipulate or edit its content later.

So what is the best practice in this concern?

I've tried two ways: either through `file_get_contents` and then loading the content to `Domdocument`, or through [Simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

For the first method, I read about it but don't know how to get the only MyDiv with `file_get_contents`.

For the second method, my current code is:

```
<?php
  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
  $url = "site.com/page1.html";
  $html = str_get_html($url);
  $elem = $html->find('div[id=MyDiv]', 0);
  echo $elem;  
?>
```

but it's also not working and I don't know why.

Comment: $elem is an object, when you display it, the prowser treat it like any other html code... check the source code to see if it's there ...

Answer (score 0):

use dom document to loadhtmnl content.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 $path = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="MDiv"]');
```